# The condition to validate the email does not work

Tags: php

in my conditions I test in order to know if the email variable
then I would like to know if the user has entered a valid email
But my code does not return me an error if the user enters a false email

```
......
// je verifie si la variable est bien remplie 
elseif (!isset($_POST["ville"]) || ($_POST["ville"]==""))
    {echo "0-5"; } 

// je verifie si la variable est bien remplie 
elseif (!isset($_POST["pays"]) || ($_POST["pays"]==""))
    {echo "0-6"; } 

// je verifie si la variable est bien remplie 
elseif (!isset($_POST["email"]) || ($_POST["email"]=="")){
    
//si la variable est remplie je regarde si c'est une vraie adresse email
    if (filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    echo "L'adresse e-mail est valide";
}else{
    echo "0-7"; }
}
```

Comment: You only enter that if block if the email is empty (not isset or equals to an empty string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done the opposite of what you need. Currently your code is not checking the validity of email because the condition is not letting to check it.

You need to check if email is being posted and if it's not empty, than you can check if it's a valid email or not.

```
// je verifie si la variable est bien remplie 
elseif (isset($_POST["email"]) && !empty($_POST["email"]){
    
//si la variable est remplie je regarde si c'est une vraie adresse email
    if (filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    echo "Email is valid";
}else{
    echo "You have to enter valid email."; }
}
```